# Predictions are right in R but different on PowerBI with same dataset

Tags: r, powerbi, regression

I'm trying to do a Dashboard on PowerBI. My current problem is that the predictions that I made in R  seems to be right, but on PowerBI using the same dataset the values are totally different.

Dataset:
https://pastebin.com/yL5BDVFH

RStudio.
[image: R Studio]

PowerBI.
[image]

Code.
[image]

Text Code:

````
database = dataset
plot(
  database$in_mask_concentration, 
  database$filtration_efficiency, 
  main="In mask concentration vs Filtration Efficiency", xlab="In mask concentration", ylab="Filtration Efficiency")

# Crear regresión
regression <- lm(filtration_efficiency ~ certification + in_mask_concentration, data=database)

new_data <- data.frame(
  certification=c('FFP2','N95','KF94','N100','KN95','Cntrl Nano','NIOSH N95'), 
  in_mask_concentration=c(2345,100, 3987, 4897, 9572, 12300,3751)
)

new_data$pred<-as.character(format(round(predict(regression, new_data), 2), nsmall = 2))


#sample_predictions2 = new_data
write.csv(new_data, "C:/Users/Administrator/dev/Python/md-master-mask/prediction/test.csv")```
````

Comment: Please please **don't** share code/data as images. It makes it basically impossible for anyone to reproduce your issue. Paste it in as plain text instead. Thanks.

Comment: Oh, sorry, code updated